# Logging Files No Found Into Text File

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a simple script that takes a list of files and copies them into a separate folder. All that's missing is a way to log a list of file names that were not found.

This seemed like something I could easily find an answer to but I've searched for hours unsuccessfully. The code I have logs the errors but I need the file names in the text file. Can someone please help?

```
for /f "delims=" %%L in (File-list.txt) do copy "%%L" H:\MovedFiles >> myscript.txt 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
do if exist "%%L" (copy...
 ) else (>>"missing files.txt" echo %%L not found at %date% %time%
)
```

will append the filenames (with bonus date and time if required) to the file "missing files.txt"

Note that spacing is important here. attempting to compress the `) else (` line by removing the spaces is likely to produce errors - which is why responses use  this format. Note that the redirectors can be placed before the `echo` which prevents problems with trailing numerics.